# Tensorflow 2 won't compile using bazel on windows 10 - package name error

Tags: windows, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to compile Tensorflow 2 c++ API on windows, using this guide: https://itnext.io/how-to-use-your-c-muscle-using-tensorflow-2-0-and-xcode-without-using-bazel-builds-9dc82d5e7f80

All dependencies where downloaded and installed.

When getting to the actual compilation command:

`bazel build -c opt — verbose_failures //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so`

taken fro within the tensorflow root directory, i get the following Error:

```
Skipping 'ù': Bad target pattern 'ù': package names may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or any of ' !"#$%&'()*+,-./;<=>?[]^_`{|}~' (most 7-bit ascii characters except 0-31, 127, ':', or '\')
```

[A snippet of the Powershell input and output related to the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHWLZ.png)

As seen in the snippet, The root directory does not contain any special characters.
I have searched the web for hours and couldn't find a solution.
Does anyone have a suggestion how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error about the command line.

Maybe you accidentally entered invalid characters that confused Bazel. I do that sometimes if I jump left and right with Ctrl+Left / Ctrl+Right and accidentally hit a key inbetween.

Try typing the command again (do not copy-paste it), and running it.
Also, it is `--verbose_failures` (starting with two `-` characters), not `- verbose_failures`.

Comment: Thanks, I omitted the "--verbose_failures" just to be on the safe side, but now I have a whole new issue, and I believe you might be able to assist. I am new to stackoverflow, should I post it here? as an edit? or maybe as a new post?

Comment: If it's a new kind of error, post a new question about it. Others facing the same problem will find it more easily, and whoever answers that question gets rewarded for that answer. Thanks!